# Relaxed binding doesn't work for composed @ConfigurationProperties names with a custom system environment property source

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have an external property source (let's say a .properties file) with environment variables like:

```
MY_PROP1=1A
MY_PROPS_PROP1=1B
MY_PROPOBJ_PROP1=1C
```

And I want to init a `@ConfigurationProperties` with those:

```
@ConfigurationProperties("my")
@Setter
@Getter
class MyProperties {

    private String prop1;
    private Props props = new Props();
    private PropsObj propsObj = new PropsObj();

    @Setter
    @Getter
    class Props {
        private String prop1;
    }

    @Setter
    @Getter
    class PropsObj {
        private String prop1;
    }
}
```

Everything is working fine when I set those as environment variables at the start of the application. But when I process those with a custom `SystemEnvironmentPropertySource` in a `EnvironmentPostProcessor`, the property `prop1` of the compose object `propsObj` is not resolved (the value is `null`):

```
class MyEnvPostProcessor implements EnvironmentPostProcessor {
    @Override
    public void postProcessEnvironment(ConfigurableEnvironment env, SpringApplication app) {
        env.getPropertySources().addLast(
            new SystemEnvironmentPropertySource(
                "myPropertySource1",
                // simplified, the map will be filled from a properties file etc:
                Map.of("MY_PROP1", "1A", "MY_PROPS_PROP1", "1B", "MY_PROPOBJ_PROP1", "1C")));
    }
}
```

Why [relaxed binding](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Relaxed-Binding-2.0) doesn't work in this case?

I'm using Spring Boot 2.2.2.RELEASE

Comment: Did you add the proper file to the `META-INF` directory for this to be detected? Also I do recall something about the `EnvironmentPostProcessor` being too late for `@ConfigurationProperties`. Finally you shouldn't be using the `SystemENvironmentPropertySource` as those are environment variables, just variables. Use the `MapPropertySource` in stead.

Comment: @M.Deinum Yes, I did, otherwise the other wouldn't work as well, but the problem is only with the compose one `MY_PROPOBJ_PROP1`. Those actually are env variables, never mind where they come from.

Comment: They aren't. Currently the are either just properties from a file, or properties you hardcoded in. Environmetn properties come from the environment. You can only have a single `SystemEnvironmentPropertySource` afaik. The binding will be handled by Spring Boot and doesn't rely on the property source.

Comment: @M.Deinum I can imagine a valid use-case where the properties come from a `.env` properties file and should be treated as environment variables in the system. That's where a custom `EnvironmentPostProcessor` is handy.

Comment: Shouldn't the `.env` be handled by the system itself, and making those available as environment variables to the process instead of the process being aware of an `.env` file?

Comment: @M. Deinum Sure, but maybe we are talking about an implementation of such a system... Best practices aside, Spring Boot offers a solution (see my answer).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the mapping Spring uses to resolve the property names. For environment variables the `SystemEnvironmentPropertyMapper` must be used to work as expected.

This mapper maps the property name into possible candidates: `MY_PROPOBJ_PROP1`, `MY_PROP_OBJ_PROP1`, `my.prop-obj.prop1`, while the default mapper results into only `my.prop-obj.prop1`. As `my.prop-obj.prop1` is not to be found in your custom property source, the value is not resolved.

To hint Spring to use the right mapper for environment properties, your property source name must end with `-systemEnvironment`, resp. with `StandardEnvironment.SYSTEM_ENVIRONMENT_PROPERTY_SOURCE_NAME`. Edit your code as follows:

```
environment.getPropertySources().addAfter(
    StandardEnvironment.SYSTEM_ENVIRONMENT_PROPERTY_SOURCE_NAME,
    new SystemEnvironmentPropertySource(
        "myPropertySource-" + StandardEnvironment.SYSTEM_ENVIRONMENT_PROPERTY_SOURCE_NAME,
        Map.of("MY_PROPOBJ_PROP1", "MyValue1")));
```